# Parsing dynamically loaded directives in Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a Vue component that makes a post request, and then outputs the returned html.

Sometimes, the html that is returned by the post contains Vue directives.

Is there a way to have Vue parse the returned html before it is output?

(In the longer term, I will rewrite this as a pure Vue solution, with the post request returning data rather than html. I'm after a short term solution if its possible).

EDIT:
Here's  my stab based on thanksd's suggestion but I'm not sure how to bind  the new Vue instance to an html element.

```
<template>
<div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="value" @change="getResults" ></input>
    <div>
        <template v-bind="results"></template>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import{eventHub} from '../utils/event.js'
export default {

    data : function(){
        return {
            value : '',
            results : {}
        }
    },

    methods:{
        getResults(){
            if(this.value.length < 3){return;}
            this.$http.post('/ajax/search',{search:this.value}).then((response)=>{
                this.results = Vue({template:response.body});       
            });
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: @thanksd I'm with you up until binding it to an html element. Have explained where I've got to in op.

Comment: See my answer. You bind a vue instance to an element by passing it or a string selector for it as the `el` property in the definition object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the post request returns you could create a new Vue instance, passing the html as the template and binding it to an element in your current Vue instance's template:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="value" @change="getResults" ></input>
    <div>
      <div id="results"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return { value: '' }
  },
  methods: {
    getResults() {
      if (this.value.length < 3) {
        return;
      }
       
      this.$http.post('/ajax/search', { search: this.value }).then((response) => {
        new Vue({ el: '#results', template: response.body });       
      });
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Or as @Bert pointed out, you could add a [`<component>` tag](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#component) to your template and pass its definition via the `is` prop:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="value" @change="getResults" ></input>
    <component :is="results"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return { 
      value: '',
      results: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getResults() {
      if (this.value.length < 3) {
        return;
      }
       
      this.$http.post('/ajax/search', { search: this.value }).then((response) => {
        this.results = { template: response.body };       
      });
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: First I think `new` is required. Nesting Vue's in general leads to issues though that's mostly because the templates are nested which isn't the case here. I honestly don't know what the behavior would be in this case. But you could create a component instead of a Vue.

Comment: Yes, it needed new, but apart from that this is working great.

Comment: Will not work with html containing interpolations ex. {{ name }}